# Internal API Server Error 500 when Posting to LinkedIn group/profile

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

Since last week I'm having the following error when my web app users try to post content to his/her wall or to group wall.

**REQUEST**:

```
 https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/811427/posts?oauth2_access_token=XXXXX
```

**POST  headers:**

```
x-li-format:json    Content-Length:1375

{
    "title": "Difunde esta vacante: #EnBuscaDe Desarrollador Java/J2ee. guadalajara.  ",
    "summary": "-",
    "content": {
        "submitted-url": "https://www.talenteca.com/empleo/mexico/guadalajara/desarrollador-javaj2ee/548724041001002d0014ba93?source=linkedin",
        "submitted-image-url": "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25038445/defaul-company-logo-temp.png",
        "title": "Desarrollador Java/J2ee",
        "description": "guadalajara. DEINTEC, empresa Mexicana líder en el desarrollo de soluciones en tecnología de Información está en búsqueda de un  Desarrollador Java/J2ee  Para un proyecto en  Gdl con el siguiente perfil:\r\n \r\n-Ingeniero en Computación, Sistemas, Informática o carrera afín\r\n-Experiencia 4 años como Desarrollador J2ee\r\n-Frameworks: Agile, Spring, Javascript, JDBC, JSP, CSS, Maven, Gradle (nice to have)\r\n-Ingles Conversacional 80 % Siendo Indispensable\r\n \r\nCompetencias:\r\n* Resolución de Problemas \r\n* Trabajo bajo presión  \r\n* Comunicación Efectiva \r\n* Proactivo\r\n \r\nTe ofrecemos: \r\n- Relación de Trabajo Largo Plazo \r\n \r\n- Formar parte de una empresa 100 % Mexicana, estable y competitiva en el mercado con oportunidad de desarrollo. Con Experiencia por más de 12 años Integrando Talento formado dentro de la empresa.    \r\n \r\nEstás interesado envía tu CV  describiendo en el asunto nombre de la vacante y expectativa económica"
    }
}
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
{
  "errorCode":0,
  "message":"Internal API server error",
  "requestId":"I329W0E239",
  "status":500,
  "timestamp":1418142926436
}
```

I'm using the LinkedIn REST API, the calls are made with Dispatch (http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)

Hope I can get some insights about this.

Comment: Hi Juan, can you provide additional details? Specifically, the full request that was made to POST the group post would be helpful. Are you consistently experiencing 500s or is it intermittent?

Comment: Hi Kamyar, just updated the answer. Few weeks ago we were consistently experiencing, now its intermittent. Thanks